# PHP sorting by number and string

Tags: php

I am sorting a database table right now by "name" using length:

```
order by LENGTH(name), name
```

Which gives me the list ordered correctly numerically but pushes anything with a character like "B" to the bottom of the list not by its counter part. Like so:

- name: 1
- name: 2
- name: 4
- name: 10
- name: 20
- name: 1-b

**What I need is:**

- name: 1
- name: 1-b
- name: 2
- name: 4
- name: 10
- name: 20

Is there a way to get ti to sort like this? I am pretty basic at PHP.

Comment: You mean a database table, not a PHP table?

Comment: `SELECT name FROM your_table ORDER BY name + 0, name`

Comment: Sorry, database table

Comment: @MarkBaker that made 1-b go after 1 correctly but now there is no natural order so it goes 1, 1-b, 10, 2, 4 as opposed to 1, 1-b, 2, 4, 10